# how to make <dl> appears on hovering on another <dl>

Tags: html, css

Been searching for 3 hours continuously but couldn't find a way to do it.
I'm so frustrated, need help.

here's my HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
        <dl class="subDL">
            <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mark Attendance &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="li-icon">&raquo;</span></a></dt>
                <dl class="subDL">
                    <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Arrival Time</a></dt>
                    <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Departing Time</a></dt>
                </dl>
            <hr size=1 width="98%" color= #003E6B />
            <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Summary</a></dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

.CSS

```
   .dropdown-content a:hover,dt:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#004d85;
}

.move:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
dt:nth-child(1):hover .li-icon{
    color: #0076bc;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #0076bc;
    font-size: 20px;
}
dl.subDL dt  > ul.subDL{
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-content dl > dt:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `.dropdown-content dl > dt:hover > ul` instead of this use `.dropdown-content dl > dt:hover > dl`

Comment: Don't use all the empty spaces (&nbsp;). just use padding or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First restructure your html so that the submenu is inside the parent `dt`:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <dl class="subDL">
        <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mark Attendance &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="li-icon">&raquo;</span></a>
            <dl class="subDL">
                <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Arrival Time</a></dt>
                <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Departing Time</a></dt>
            </dl>
        </dt>
        <hr size=1 width="98%" color= #003E6B />
        <dt><a href="#">-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Summary</a></dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Then replace your ul's in the css with dl (as you don't use uls..):

```
.dropdown-content a:hover,dt:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#004d85;
}

.move:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
dt:nth-child(1):hover .li-icon{
    color: #0076bc;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #0076bc;
    font-size: 20px;
}
dl.subDL dt  > dl.subDL{
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-content dl > dt:hover > dl{
    display: block;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvj6ydhr/).